# Apache2 Fastcgi php-fpm shows white page

Tags: apache2, fastcgi

Can anyone please provide me step by step the way i can run apache2 on fast-cgi on ubuntu 22.10, I tried several thing but either I get a blank page either errors
I am on new installed Apache2 server instance.

Thnx!!!!

Tried many thngs but wth unveil

Comment: Have you check the apache error log?